# I am running UBUNTU 14.04.4 LTS on an ACER Aspire laptop

Tags: 14.04

I am running UBUNTU 14.04.4 LTS on an ACER Aspire laptop..I need help to install SKYPE, Install MakeMKV DVD ripping software and 
to detect ANDROID devices for transferring files from my laptop to the 
Tablets/Smart-phones.
Is there a tool in Ubuntu similar to the Snipping tool in Windows 7 ?
Is it possible to get a unit conversion tool that works in Ubuntu.The tool
that I used in Windows (Convert.EXE) does not work in Ubuntu.
Any step by step help in this regard is greatly appreciated.
One more question: Does Ubuntu support any 3D modeling softwares?

Answer (score 2):

1. Enable all Ubuntu repos, update and then open Ubuntu software centre
2. Install Skype from there
3. For MakeMKV, check this https://gist.github.com/knugie/b0e7ea8f6d79315cc0e6
4. I believe, your Android will be automatically detected with an USB Data Cable, if not, you can use Bluetooth for data transfer
5. Ubuntu has Shutter as snipping tool, can be installed from the software centre
6. ConvertAll is your unit conversation software, available in software centre
7. For 3D modelling, there is nothing like Blender, it's in software centre too

Hope it helps

Comment: Adding packages like mtpfs and mtp-tools might help with some issues.

Comment: I cannot find Skype in the Ubuntu software centre.

Comment: Need more info: for installing MakeMKV...

Comment: Skype is in Partners repository, you have to enable that, then update and install Skype. For MakeMKV, please follow the commands step by step on the website I mentioned.

Comment: OK guys, Thank you for the help, I was able to install all of the above softwares.

Comment: Glad we could help